# Why does this give unexpected return value?

Tags: java, if-statement, substring, return-value

the same code when solving problems on codingbat works , but not in my IDE

```
public class Bark {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lo = "hi there";
    String shank = lo.substring(0 , 2);
    if (shank.equals("hi")) return true;
    else return false;
}}
```

Comment: The return type of main is void. You're returning booleans. boolean is not void. It's boolean. You're not supposed to return a boolean from a method whose return type is void.

Comment: @JBNizet why was it working on codingbat then?

Comment: It probable wasn't. Or codingbats doesn't actually execute the code you post, but modifies it before compiling and running it.

Comment: @JBNizet ok thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess here is that your expectations have to with an artifact of some sort.  Certainly, the check on `shank` should reveal that it is equal to `hi`.  You are returning a boolean value from a method which is `void`, and has no return type.  Consider the following version, which works as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lo = "hi there";
    String shank = lo.substring(0 , 2);
    if ("hi".equals(shank)) {
        System.out.println("EQUAL");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("NOT EQUAL");
    }
}
```

Perhaps CodingBat has some hooks into your code which aren't so obvious, resulting in the code "working" there, but not in your IDE.